# write ODE equations as a set of first order equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried but I don't know how to write these ODE equations as a set of first order equations. Could someone please tell me how to write them?

$$m_1\ddot x_1 + (_1 + _2)_1 − _2_2 = 0 $$
$$m_2\ddot x_2 − _2_1 + _2_2 = 0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Thanks for using good formatting.  On this site, you need to include what you have tried, your work so far, what you know, so we know how to help you.

Comment: The trick generally is to make $y =\dot  x$ a new variable, so $\dot y = \ddot x$, so it seems you need to do that twice and get $4$ equations.

Answer (score 0):

Define the first derivatives as new variables:
$$v_1 = \dot{x}_1, \qquad v_2 = \dot{x}_2.$$
Then you can form the system of equations
$$m_1 \dot{v}_1 + (k_1 + k_2) x_1 - k_2 x_2 = 0, \\ m_2 \dot{v}_2 - k_2 x_1 + k_2 x_2 = 0, \\ v_1 = \dot{x}_1, \\ v_2 = \dot{x}_2. $$
You could also write this as a linear system:
$$\begin{Bmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2 \\ \dot{v}_1 \\ \dot{v}_2\end{Bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -\frac{k_1+k_2}{m_1} & \frac{k_2}{m_1} & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{k_2}{m_2} & -\frac{k_2}{m_2} & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{Bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ v_1 \\ v_2\end{Bmatrix}$$

Comment: But there is no X dot , it has X double dot.

Comment: X double dot becomes V dot